# dispatch is not a function - redux in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, middleware

I am having problems with using redux for asynchronous operation.
I initially did it like this:

```
export function fetchProducts(request) {
  console.log("called1");

  return async function (dispatch) {
    console.log("called2");
    try {
      dispatch(setLoading(true));
      const response = await axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
      dispatch(setProducts(response.data));
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      dispatch(setError(error.message));
    } finally {
      dispatch(setLoading(false));
    }
  };
}
```

But the inner function was not getting called.

So i tried this:

```
export function fetchProducts(request) {
  console.log("called1");

  async function fetcher(dispatch) {
    console.log("called2");
    try {
      dispatch(setLoading(true));
      const response = await axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
      dispatch(setProducts(response.data));
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      dispatch(setError(error.message));
    } finally {
      dispatch(setLoading(false));
    }
  }

  fetcher();
}
```

Now it says dispatch is not a function.

What do i do?

Comment: how are you calling the fetchProducts function from inside your component?

Answer (score 0):

In your second Function, you are creating function inside another function & which takes dispatch as params .

Your First Method , you are using hooks inside your HOC . You can use it like

```
 export function fetchProducts() {
  return async function (dispatch) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } 
  };
}
```

```
 const dispatch = useDispatch()
 dispatch(fetchProducts());
```